# Playing a DRM m3u8 file in FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, drm

I'm attempting to play a Adobe Access DRM protected file in FFMPEG. Here is an example of the type of file I am trying to play: http://drmtest2.adobe.com/Content/FAXS4/Anonymous_REMOTE/sample.mp4.m3u8

This file works perfectly (as expected) in Adobe's DRM test player (http://drmtest2.adobe.com:8080/AccessPlayer/player.html) but not in ffmpeg. Here is the log:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto" -i http://drmtest2.adobe.com/Content/FAXS4/Anonymous_REMOTE/sample.mp4.m3u8 -c copy output.ts
ffmpeg version N-89508-g1f1207145a Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
  libavcodec     58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  7.100 /  7.  7.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[hls,applehttp @ 0000024ae8b79e00] Opening 'https://drmtest2.adobe.com:8444/faxsks/adobe/key' for reading
[https @ 0000024ae8b988e0] HTTP error 500 Internal Server Error
Unable to open key file https://drmtest2.adobe.com:8444/faxsks/adobe/key
[hls,applehttp @ 0000024ae8b79e00] Opening 'crypto+http://drmtest2.adobe.com/Content/FAXS4/Anonymous_REMOTE/fileSequence0.ts' for reading
[hls,applehttp @ 0000024ae8b79e00] Error when loading first segment 'http://drmtest2.adobe.com/Content/FAXS4/Anonymous_REMOTE/fileSequence0.ts'
http://drmtest2.adobe.com/Content/FAXS4/Anonymous_REMOTE/sample.mp4.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I have a strong suspicion that it isn't possible to play these types of files within FFmpeg, if not is there an alternate (even Adobe provided) player that I can use?